# Fetch mobile contacts

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Is ther any way to fetch mobile contacts in sencha touch 2 and not using phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way as of yet to do this in ST2 directly... you have to use phonegap or something similar